# Import data in ProtocolBuffer format

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to import data in BigQuery in a ProtocolBuffer format? I have a (very) large set of data already in this format, and I would like now to push them into BigQuery. But if I can avoid the translation to json or so, I would be delighted. Plus this would definitely save me some bandwidth...

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, not currently possible.  We support CSV and JSON for import.

Please comment on my answer about the use case or reach out via google+ or twitter so we can consider this as a feature request.

Comment: I come back to you. After some studies on our side, we could definitely use ProtoBuf as an import format. As we plan on importing a lot of data, we can definitely benefit from this feature! All of our data are pretty simple, but have a record field, which implies a json-based solution to push them into your solution, which in definitely not convenient for us. That would save us a lot of bandwidth, and we would not have to convert all of our existing data from protobuf to json, then do the exact converse on your side.